# right join table status with number of member count with where / having condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two table, one is member another is member_status table. I need to get the count of the number of member in the same status.

member

```
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | full_name   | mobile_no | address | status | remark | edit_user_id | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | John Doe    | 123       |         | 1      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  2 | Michael Bay | 123       |         | 1      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  3 | Hey Hey     | 123       |         | 3      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

member_status

```
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                | description          | status | edit_user_id | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Visitor             | Visitor              | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  3 | Member              | Member               | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  4 | Level 1             | Level 1              | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
| 11 | Level 12            | Level 12             | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-07-03 17:27:00 | 2014-07-03 17:27:00 |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I had tried this query, but it is NOT CORRECT output...

```
select `member_status`.`name`, count(member.id) as totalNum
from member WHERE member.created_at between '2014-06-01 00:00:00' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59'
right join `member_status` on (member.`status` = `member_status`.id) 
group by `member_status`.name
```

This is output I would like to have it

```
+---------------------+----------+
| name                | totalNum |
+---------------------+----------+
| Level 1             |        0 |
| Level 12            |        0 |
| Member              |        1 |
| Visitor             |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

However, somehow, the output is this one, I would like out all the output

```
+---------------------+----------+
| name                | totalNum |
+---------------------+----------+
| Member              |        1 |
| Visitor             |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: you may need a left join.

Comment: please show your answer, I tried either. The problem is it did not show up all the member_status. It's work without where / having condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT      MS.name, 
            count(M.id) as totalNum           
FROM        member_status MS
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT * FROM member WHERE created_at between '2014-06-01 00:00:00' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59') M ON M.[status]  = MS.id
GROUP BY    MS.name
```

You must LEFT JOIN like above.

I just edited the code. Please see.

Comment: It still display like what my actual result, but I want my expected result

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    MS.name, COUNT(*) AS totalNum
FROM
    member_status MS
    LEFT JOIN member M ON MS.id = M.status
    AND
    M.created_at between '2014-06-01 00:00:00' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY 
    MS.name
ORDER BY totalNum

Comment: It still display like what my actual result, but I want my expected result

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is put the where condition under the ON condition

```
select `member_status`.`name`, count(member.id) as totalNum
from member WHERE 
right join `member_status` on (member.`status` = `member_status`.id AND member.created_at between '2014-06-01 00:00:00' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59') 
group by `member_status`.name
```